# How to reduce the time for converting the cudf dataframe to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a project which has heavy computations.So I am using GPU-Accelerated RAPIDSAI libraries CUDF.I have got the access of CUDF but I am not able to iterate the data frame of CUDF using '.iloc' which will help in calculating a statistical parameter.
COMMAND I AM USING :
SET_3 = cudf.DataFrame()

.....Do the middle process.......

```
SET_3_PROFIT = []

for i in tqdm(range(len(df.columns))):

    SET_3_PROFIT.append(sum(SET_3.iloc[:,i]))  # ERROR IN THIS LINE
print(len(SET_3_PROFIT))
```

here `'SET_3.iloc[:,i]'` is not working, 
so I am converting this data frame into PANDAS dataframe

Comment: Hey Tanmay, can we have a simple minimal reproducible example for your question?